# Why video in aframe doesn't work on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr

I tested my web-VR app (I used Aframe). On the desktop, everything works great. But on my phone (Android OS) video don't play. Any suggestions?

Link to app:
https://mateuszlesko.github.io/ElblagAFrame/video.html

```
<a-assets>
                    <video id="penguin-sledding" autoplay='False' loop="false" material.repeat='None' src="Elblag1945.mp4">
                  </a-assets>

                  <!-- Using the asset management system. -->
<a-video src="#penguin-sledding" width="26" height="15" position="0 0 -20"></a-video>
```

Comment: You have Google vr services installed?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile browsers limit video autoplay. Video playback has to be triggered by a user gesture. More info in [A-Frame FAQ](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-video-not-play-on-mobile). Also make sure that [video format and codecs are supported](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load) in your device / browser / OS version.